# std::partition error when partitioning a vector of a type of object

Tags: c++, c++11

Am using the following line of code to partition a number of objects through the following code:

```
vector<PrimitiveBvhRepresentation>::iterator lastFirst = std::partition(first, last, &Engine::BVHNode::MiddlePointPartition);
```

the partition functions makes use of the following function to determine if the respective objects in the vector are true or false.

```
bool MiddlePointPartition(PrimitiveBvhRepresentation current)
{
    if (splittingAxis == 0)
    {
        return current.boundingBoxCentroid.x <= splittingAxisValue;
    }
    else if (splittingAxis == 1)
    {
        return current.boundingBoxCentroid.y <= splittingAxisValue;
    }
    else
    {
        return current.boundingBoxCentroid.z <= splittingAxisValue;
    }
}
```

yet upon execution i get the following error:

```
Error   63  error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

When clicking on the error it takes me to the algorithm class. Is the reference to the function written wrong?

Comment: Try changing the function signature to `bool MiddlePointPartition(PrimitiveBvhRepresentation const& current)`

Comment: @CoryKramer didnt work :/

Comment: Is it a non static member function?

Answer (score 2):

Non static member functions are not functions.

Try this:

```
auto lastFirst = std::partition(first, last,
  [this](auto const& x){return MiddlePointPartition(x);}
);
```

in C++14.  In C++11 replace the `auto const&` with `PrimitiveBvhRepresentation const&`.

In C++03, consider a new compiler, or use `std::bind(&mem_fun, this)` as the 3rd argument to `partition` instead of the lambda.

Comment: If `MiddlePointPartition` is non-static, this only works in a context you can capture `this` (i.e., a member of `PrimitiveBvhRepresentation`)?

Comment: @T.C. yes, but I assume we must be in such a context.  People rarely think member function pointers to a completely different, unnamed object are magical.  They often think member function pointers to members of this are.  If I am wrong, fixing it is easy, but if I am right, the fix will be noise.

Answer (score 0):

The standard algorithms require a function object that can be used with the normal function call syntax, so a pointer to member doesn't qualify. If you need a non-static member function, wrap it with `std::mem_fn`.

`std::partition` requires a unary predicate, but your member function, assuming that it is non-static, takes two arguments (the implicit `this` parameter, and `current`). It's not clear to me whether you'd want this function to be a static member, or just operate on `this`.